# Paramiko exec_command not working with mkfs?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash, filesystems, paramiko

Some issue executing the following bash with Paramiko:

```py
def format_disk(self, device, size, dformat, mount, name):
        stdin_, stdout_, stderr_ = self.client.exec_command(f"pvcreate {device};" \
        f"vgcreate {name}-vg {device};" \
        f"lvcreate -L {size} --name {name}-lv {name}-vg;" \
        f"mkfs.{dformat} /dev/{name}-vg/{name}-lv;" \
        f"mkdir {mount};" \
        f"echo '/dev/{name}-vg/{name}-lv {mount} {dformat} defaults 0 0' >> /etc/fstab")
        print(f"mkfs.{dformat} /dev/{name}-vg/{name}-lv;")
```

Print statement outputs: `mkfs.ext4 /dev/first_try-vg/first_try-lv;` If I copy and paste this exact command on the server there are no errors and it formats the disk as expected.

#### Troubleshooting steps

Server before running python script:

```
ls: cannot access /first_try: No such file or directory
[root@localhost ~]# vgs
[root@localhost ~]# lvs
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/fstab 

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Thu Feb 25 07:32:51 2021
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=38b7e96a-71e5-4089-a348-bd23828f9dc8 /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=72fd2a6a-85db-4596-9fc2-6604d0d865a3 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
```

Server after running python script:

```sh
[root@localhost ~]# ls /first_try/
[root@localhost ~]# vgs
  VG           #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree  
  first_try-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <20.00g <15.00g
[root@localhost ~]# lvs
  LV           VG           Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  first_try-lv first_try-vg -wi-a----- 5.00g                                                    
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/fstab 

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Thu Feb 25 07:32:51 2021
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=38b7e96a-71e5-4089-a348-bd23828f9dc8 /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=72fd2a6a-85db-4596-9fc2-6604d0d865a3 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/first_try-vg/first_try-lv /first_try ext4 defaults 0 0
[root@localhost ~]# mount -a
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/first_try--vg-first_try--lv,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

The error from `mount -a` indicates that the disk is not formatted.
If I format the disk manually and run `mount -a` it works.

Example:

```sh
[root@localhost ~]# mkfs.ext4 /dev/first_try-vg/first_try-lv
mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
327680 inodes, 1310720 blocks
65536 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=1342177280
40 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): mdone
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done 

[root@localhost ~]# mount -a
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3                                 18G  4.7G   14G  27% /
devtmpfs                                 471M     0  471M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                    487M     0  487M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                    487M  8.4M  478M   2% /run
tmpfs                                    487M     0  487M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                                297M  147M  151M  50% /boot
tmpfs                                     98M   12K   98M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                                     98M     0   98M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/mapper/first_try--vg-first_try--lv  4.8G   20M  4.6G   1% /first_try
```

Comment: Does it work with the `ssh`? Like `ssh user@host "pvcreate device; vgcreate name-vg device ; lvcreate -L size --name name-lv name-vg ; mkfs.dformat /dev/name-vg/name-lv; ..."` – on **1 line**.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  Yes, that does work

Comment: If you want to log errors, you have to do `> error 2>&1`. You can not do `2>&1 > error`.

Comment: @thatotherguy I just tried it that way and there is no `error` file. It still runs the rest of the commands though.

Comment: How did you determine that the commands didn't work? Is there an error message?

Comment: So show us a complete transcript of the `ssh ...` session (also a screenshot might be useful). + A [Mcve] for your Python problem (with as little commands as possible – Can you for example even display `mkfs` usage screen via Paramiko?), including complete output that you receive from `stdout_` and `stderr_`.

Comment: @thatotherguy It doesn't work because the disk isn't formatted to `ext4` and won't mount from `/etc/fstab` because of that. If I run `mkfs` manually on the server I am able to run `mount -a` and mount the drive properly because all of the rest of the steps did work. `mkfs` is the only piece that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pariminko could not handle the output from `mkfs`. I changed the command to use the `-q` quiet flag and was able to get the script to run successfully.

New commmand `mkfs -q -t {dformat} /dev/{name}-vg/{name}-lv`

Comment: Good that you have found a solution. But your statement is wrong. There's *no output that Paramiko cannot handle*. It all about your code, which you didn't show us.

Comment: I wrote what I look for in a comment to your question above. You never responded.